# Construct URL before rendering nextjs page for meta data

Tags: next.js

On my page, I've got some meta data:

```
const MyPage= () => {
  const router = useRouter();


  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
        ...
        <meta name="twitter:image" content={`https://...${router.query.id}.jpg`} />
      </Head>
    ...
    </>
  );
};
```

The image URL needs to be resolve before the page is rendered, this is how twitter can display the image when sharing the page.

I'm not sure how to construct this URL beforehand. I think it has something to do with `getStaticProps`, probably... I've tried this:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    return {
      props: { twitterImage: `https://...${params.id}.jpg` }, 
    }
}
```

Then use this props in my page. But got the following error:

```
Unhandled error during request: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') at getStaticProps
```

How can I construct the URL and pass it as props to the page?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the issue with using the `router` instance to get the data? Is the metadata not there if you inspect the page source?

Comment: It is there. But somehow Twitter cannot reach it on time. I guess the Twitter bot crawls the metadata before the page renders the metadata

Comment: What you see in the page source is what's returned by the server, and that's what the bots will see too. The issue may lie somewhere else.